# Constantly Receiving Application Error when Changing Activity - Android

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to change activities in my Android project, but every time I do so, I received an Application Error. I am new to Android so I may be making lots of mistakes. I've looked at many possible answers and have found none that help me.

MainActivity

```
package com.android.azultech.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final FloatingActionButton fab;
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Open Developer Twitter", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                onTwitter(fab);
            }
        });

//        final Button btn;
//        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
//        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                  // Snackbar.make(view, "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                  //         .setAction("Action", null).show();
//                   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HelpScreen.class);
//
//                   view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
//               }
//           });

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void some_function(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HelpScreen.class);

        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void onTwitter(FloatingActionButton fab) {
        Intent intent = null;
        try {
            this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=3146095821"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/itsazul_"));
        }
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_help) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, HelpScreen.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_quit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "MainScreen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.android.azultech.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "MainScreen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.android.azultech.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

HelpScreen

```
package com.android.azultech.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class HelpScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_help_screen);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Open Developer Twitter", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }

    });

}
```

}

And here is where the button is declared in the content_main_screen.xml

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Help"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:onClick="some_function"/>
```

Here is the Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.azultech.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelpScreen" />

        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.android.azultech.myapplication.MainScreen">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_screen" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:tint="#24a5b3" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.android.azultech.myapplication.MainScreen"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_screen"
        android:background="#4f4a4a">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project Shadow"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#e4dddd"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="262dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Please Note: This app will continue in development for the next few months. It&apos;s current state will not be the final one."
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help"
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:onClick="some_function"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please upload your mainifest file.

Comment: Please add manifest file and also upload error logs

Comment: I've added the manifest file, though I am unsure of how to access the error logs.

Comment: Where is `onTwitter` method?

Comment: Could you please write the error message you are receiving

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I updated it.

Comment: @sankyjain I'm not receiving an error message. My only issue is when I run the app on my physical device and press the button, the app crashes. All it tells me is that there was an Application Error and that the app is no longer responsive.

Comment: Please run it once on emulator and check the logs, and write the error you are receiving. Without seeing the error message it is very difficult to know the cause

Comment: I attempted to run an emulator, but it crashed on me. I'll try it again tomorrow to get the crash log.

Comment: @sankyjain I can't get you crash logs from an emulator. I can't run the emulators on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your are looking for fab button but you want btn button. But I don't see where you inflate content_main_screen.

So I'm going to go progresively. First it works with your layout like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm gonna edit trying to put your layout in a way that he function.

Edit2: Well it actually works on my phone. Can you acceed to the first Activity or your activity crash directly ? Can you show me your logcat error ?(all the red lines) Do you have twitter install on your phone ? Is it the twitter button that crash or the help button ?

Comment: By chance, could the inflation thing be included in the onStop and onStart default included functions? I think I forgot to include those as well.

Comment: You have to set the content of you activity with a layout. You do that on the oncreatemethod. But you said that the button is on the layout content_main_screen. But i dont see where you do setcontentview(R.id.content_main_screen).

Comment: Adding setContentView(R.id.content_main_screen) gives me an error. setContentView(R.layout.content_main_screen) causes my program to crash.

Comment: You have to set the content of your activity just one time. But when you do findviewbyid you have to be sure that the view is on the layout you just set. In your code you do findViewById(R.id.fab), do you have 2 fab in your code ? , nothing wrong about that if you have 2, but if you just one in the layout "blabla" for exemple and you set 2 content different in your activity, it's gonna crash. Setcontentview will charge the layout. And findviewbyid will look for the view inside the layout you set. So make sure you have 2 fab button, one in activity_help_screen and one in activity_main_screen.

Comment: You can edit posting all your code for me to see more clearly ;)

Comment: I've updated the original question with all code. If you need my XML files, I can also update with those.

Comment: If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide me the activity_main_screen.xml file and your app crash you click on the fab button right ?

Comment: Currently I don't have the fab button assigned to open a new activity. I have a regular button doing that, but the program crashes any time I try to change activities. activity_main_screen.xml has been added though.

Comment: The button I am using is in content_main_screen.xml by the way.

Comment: I just let your button and it works lol so I deleted all the other ViewGroup/View/Widget, I'm gonna edit

Comment: (This is my other account) It is the help button that crashes the program. Twitter works just fine. Where would I find the logcat error? If it works fine for you, I might just find a tutorial and follow that instead of trying to find bits and pieces on the internet and piece them together.